# NoneType: TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python

I am reading an Excel file with openpyxl and rows are getting parsed as tuple objects. One of the objects in the tuple can be a NoneType. Further in the code rows are compared with other rows. These last rows don't have  a NoneType, but are a empty String object, which hampers the comparison. So I'm using the following code to replace the NoneType by an empty String object.

```
                for row in previous_worksheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
                    print("row " + str(type(row)))
                    for x in range(len(list(row))):
                        print(type(row[x]))
                        if row[x] is None:
                            print(row[x])
                            row[x] = ""
```

Running this code gives me the following output:

```
row <class 'tuple'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'NoneType'>
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\SecuniaComparer\secunia_comparer.py", line 187, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\SecuniaComparer\secunia_comparer.py", line 182, in main
    sc.start_parsing()
  File "C:\PycharmProjects\SecuniaComparer\secunia_comparer.py", line 71, in start_parsing
    row[x] = ""
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

The object is a NoneType, but assigning an empty String results in a TypeError for a tuple object. How can I fix this?

Comment: No, the object you're trying to assign to is `row`, a `tuple`, which doesn't support item assignment.

Comment: tuple are immutable. It means you can't modify them. You have 2 solutions : create a new tuple or create a custom comparator

Comment: `row = tuple('' if i is None else i for i in row)`…?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, creating a new list object solves the issue.

```
temp_row = list(row)
for x in range(len(temp_row)):
    if temp_row[x] is None:
        temp_row[x] = ("")
self.previous_results.append(tuple(temp_row))
```